# Cannot reference variable created with "vars()[]" from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tkinter

I am tasked with creating in inventory management system for a comic book store as a school python assessment. I currently have a dictionary that has the names of the comics and the stock values of these comics imported from a CSV file;

```
comic_books =  {}

with open('data.csv', 'r+',  newline='') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in csvreader:
        comic_books[row[0]] = int(row[1])
```

One of the programs requirements is to ensure the user can see the stock of all comics at once. To do this, I simply created two label widgets for each key in my dictionary using the `vars()` function (alongside some formatting to ensure things like spaces in the comic names didn't cause conflicts);

```
itteration = 2

for item in comic_books:

    vars()[item.replace(" ", "") + "Stock"] = Label(main, text=item+":")
    vars()[item.replace(" ", "") + "Stock"].grid(column=1, row=itteration, padx=5)

    vars()[item.replace(" ", "") + "StockAmount"] = Label(main, text=comic_books[item])
    vars()[item.replace(" ", "") + "StockAmount"].grid(column=2, row=itteration, padx=5)
    itteration += 1
```

I eventually got below result, which works as expected:

[image]

Basically, my problem is that I am tying to refer to one of these variables later in my code (specifically, this is part of the code that runs when the user sells a comic, in order to update the labels with the new values);

```
for item in comic_books:
                vars()[item.replace(" ", "") + "StockAmount"].config(text=comic_books[item])
```

This is not working, and whenever the program tries to run the line above, I get this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\pythonAsessment2\test.py", line 114, in sellProcess
    vars()[item.replace(" ", "") + "Stock"].config(text=comic_books[item])
KeyError: 'Comic2Stock'
```

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you know your emailadress used for you other account... if so you can send request to SO.

Comment: Why are you even using `vars` here? **You should not use dynamically created variables**. Use a *container*, like a `dict`

Comment: Note, `vars()` either returns the global namespace, i.e. `globals()` or the local namespace (if in a function), i.e. `locals()`. Modifications to `globals()` dictionaries will actually affect the global namespace, modifications to `locals()` **will not actually affect the local namespace**, and if you created your "variables" in the global scope, then try to access them using `vars()` in a function, they will fail. Don't use dynamic variables. **Use a dict**. You are already *using* dicts, just ones that don't work how you want them to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm at a loss as to what to do at this point.

The first thing to do is stop using `vars()` to create dynamic variables. That is almost never a good idea as it makes your code needlessly complex, hard to write, and hard to debug.

Instead, use a dictionary if you want to reference individual items by name. It would look something like this:

```
labels = {}
for item in comic_books:
    key= "{} Stock".format(item)
    labels[key] = Label(main, text=item+":")
    labels[key].grid(column=1, row=itteration, padx=5)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate. I am at school right now and my Digital Technologies class is about to end, so I will give this a shot when I get home. Thanks again

Comment: Sorry to get back to you so late, had a bit of a hectic weekend. Have marked as "answered". Thanks again for the response (: